# Airflow task won't start because Failed to fetch log file from worker. Request URL is missing

Tags: airflow-scheduler

I have several task in our dag that won't start running. When I checked the airflow log, there was an error and the error was below.
FYI , we are using Airflow 2.2.5
*** Log file does not exist:
*** Fetching from:
*** Failed to fetch log file from worker. Request URL is missing an 'http://' or 'https://' protocol.
Does anybody can help me resolving this issue?
Thank you